# Why do I get an "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished" error when trying to run my rspec 2.99 tests with Rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have a Rails app that I'm upgrading to Rails 4.1.4. I also have an RSpec test suite that I want to run against the app with the updated Rails version. The application does *not* use a database, just communicates with services. However, when I try to run the tests, I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
   ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:499:in `create_fixtures'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:984:in `load_fixtures'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:957:in `setup_fixtures'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:806:in `before_setup'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-rails-2.99.0/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_exec'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/extensions/instance_eval_with_args.rb:16:in `instance_eval_with_args'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:241:in `instance_eval_with_args'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:104:in `call'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:104:in `run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:446:in `run_hook'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:462:in `run_around_each_hooks'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:250:in `with_around_each_hooks'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:113:in `run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:514:in `block in run_examples'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:510:in `map'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:510:in `run_examples'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:495:in `run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `map'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:24:in `block in run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:58:in `report'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:21:in `run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:103:in `run'
 # /Users/karianneberg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/rspec-core-2.99.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I don't understand why it's trying to fire up active record

The application runs just fine when I don't run it though tests, and the tests run just fine on Rails 4.0. I'm still using RSpec-rails 2.99. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: It seems to be related to this issue on Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11547, this issue on rspec-rails: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/1141 and this commit on Rails itself: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6d10d64cbafe70e343cef0f94e015908b9348ac5#comments. Still bummed about how to fix it, though.

Comment: The short version is that rails will try to connect to load fixtures if ActiveRecord is loaded. If you're not requiring AR yourself then something else probably is (the example in the issue you linked to was carrierwave)

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'm not doing it myself explicitly, but I am using `Bundler.require` in `application.rb` and have rails listed as a gem in `Gemfile`, which I guess is doing it.

Comment: Have you tried setting a test database of sqlite3? When testing gems I use `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3", :database => ":memory:")` in the spec/spec_helper.rb file. If it's actually trying to access the database for some reason, you can just create a schema file and load it: `load File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/schema.rb'` - not ideal certainly, but if you end up hitting your head against a brick wall...

Comment: @AFaderDarkly Thanks for the tip. I tried that, and it works. It is however not pretty. I really hope the rails team fixes this issue. This will have to do in the meantime, though.

Comment: Glad I could get you moving again.